# Positioning in css and html with bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a block of 5 blocks of the same width with margins of 10px whose first div is in a fixed position or does not scroll, All responsible or aligns verticalment mobile. https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Belleza' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

```
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
}
._bloc{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #122b40;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Div Fixed 
    2
    3
    4
    5

Comment: What you exactly trying for? clear explanation needed.

Comment: hi I use bootstrap and I want to 5 div with the first div which remains fixed to scroll

Comment: ...and why Bootstrap?...Bootstrap doesn't have **anything** like this.

Comment: It's true I try with flexbox but I can not manage has the first div is being fixed

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096729/fixed-div-next-to-5-fluid-divs .It may be helpfull

Comment: Thank you is great but I love that the first block is not fixed scroll

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hard to understand but I think you are trying something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 myDiv"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 myDiv"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 myDiv"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 myDiv"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 myDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Where `myDiv` would be :

```
.myDiv {
   width: 50px //enter what you want
}

.myDiv > div {
   position: fixed;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you is great but I love that the first block is not fixed scroll

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand. Please use proper terms. Anyway, as I understand it, you need a responsive block.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12">Block 1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12">Block 2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12">Block 3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12">Block 4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12">Block 5</div>
</div>
```

This will show five blocks for desktop and tablets and one block for mobile devices.

Comment: Thank you is great but I love that the first block is not fixed scroll